# Reference for "Discrete differential Geometry"

Tags: differential-geometry, reference-request, numerical-methods, computational-geometry

Can you suggest some references for "Discrete differential geometry" for beginners?

My background is Elementary Differential Geometry (Curves and Surfaces)/ Computational Geometry / Numerical Methods, what specifically I'm looking for is a good reference that explaines how to discretize operators tipically defined in differential geometry, when we model our geometry as a mesh.

Comment: I find the following references via *google*: [Discrete Differential Geometry: An Applied Introduction
Keenan Crane](https://www.cs.cmu.edu/~kmcrane/Projects/DDG/paper.pdf) and [en.wikipedia.org](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Discrete_differential_geometry).

Comment: @Armandoj18eos I gave it a glance and it looks like an excellent reference indeed.

Comment: Bear in mind the "Elementary Differential Geometry", I already see wedge products etc.